# Group Multiple columns while performing multiple aggregations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to group by multiple columns and perform several different aggregations. Grouping by type and date and taking average of en, en2, stat1 and stat2.

**Data**

```
type    en  en2 date       stat1    stat2
aa      40  80  1/1/2021    1       1
aa      20  20  1/1/2021    2       1  
aa      10  10  1/1/2021    3       5  
bb      10  10  1/1/2021    3       9
bb      50  5   1/1/2021    5       1
aa      90  5   1/7/2021    5       2
aa      100 10  1/7/2021    1       5
bb      80  10  1/7/2021    5       2
```

**Desired**

```
type    en  en2 date       stat1    stat2
aa      23  36  1/1/2021    2       3
bb      30  7.5 1/1/2021    4       5
aa      95  7.5 1/7/2021    3       3.5
bb      80  10  1/7/2021    5       2
```

**Doing**

```
grouped = final.groupby(['date'],['type']) \
.agg({'en':'mean', 'en2':'mean','stat1':'mean','stat2':'mean'})
```

I am getting a typeError. - Unhashable list
I am researching.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: could you add the error message, please?

Comment: sure I updated @AhmedElashry

Comment: When you group by multiple columns you specify the labels together in a **single** list: `.groupby(['date', 'type'])...`

Comment: right ok I've just updated my script- thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grouped = final.groupby(['date', 'type'], as_index=False) \
               .agg({'type': 'first', 'en': 'mean', 'en2': 'mean',
                     'date': 'first', 'stat1': 'mean', 'stat2': 'mean'})
print(grouped)

# Output
  type         en        en2      date  stat1     stat2
0   aa  23.333333  36.666667  1/1/2021    2.0  2.333333
1   bb  30.000000   7.500000  1/1/2021    4.0  5.000000
2   aa  95.000000   7.500000  1/7/2021    3.0  3.500000
3   bb  80.000000  10.000000  1/7/2021    5.0  2.000000
```

Comment: thank you @corralien- what is the significance of placing 'first' for the type and date fields? is this placing the position?

Comment: Oh I get an error that is saying DataError: No numeric types to aggregate - however I have numeric datatypes in the columns here @corralien

Comment: As you can see I used `as_index = False` in` groupby` to keep the column order, so I need to keep a value for these 2 columns to not lose them. `first` is a good choice because all values are the same for them.

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: oh I did df.dtype I see some are objects- I will cast to float and retry

Comment: this works thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
grouped = final[['date', 'type', 'en',
               'en2','stat1','stat2']].groupby(['date', 'type'],
                as_index=False, dropna=False).sum()
```

Comment: thank you I keep getting keyerror although my columns are in the dataframe @script